# How can we flag unnecessary edit on Question and Answer

Tags: discussion, edits, flags

Is there any option to indicate flag for unnecessary edit on questions and answers ? I have seen many times people unnecessary edit my question or answer whether it is in proper formatting and complete information.

Comment: Could you share an example of such an edit? As long as it does improve something, there's nothing to flag about, really.

Comment: See my this question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829246/whats-wrong-in-add-method-to-validate-date-format-in-yyyy-dd-mm . when i have asked this question ,each and everything is same. even I always take care formatting of my question so that it will better readable to user

Comment: That first edit wasn't the best - just removing [jQuery] wasn't very useful, should have added [regex] and [javascipt] instead IMO. Hardly worth complaining about though. Roll it back if you don't like it, only flag if the user persists or if it's actually "vandalism".

Comment: The edit seemed reasonable although it left some issues untouched. Unless an edit actively makes something worse don't flag it. We like collaborative editing for the greater good.

Comment: See one more example here :-  I am not a single person who face this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976437/font-size-does-not-affect-value-0-1-to-0-4-em#16976437

Comment: @Roopendra you should avoid using HTML for formatting your question. It's especially useless on lists.

Comment: Again not a problem. Don't flag that.

Comment: @Roopendra - Editing on your question [by Flexo](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16829246/3) was completely valid. I don't see any issue there. He removed salutation, improved formatting. Also regex and javascript tags are valid for that question IMO.

Comment: @ dystroy, thanks for suggestion. I just raise this because I have seen such problem many times. I have given my question link just for an example. If anything is usefully for me than I really appreciate people who taught me .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976437/font-size-does-not-affect-value-0-1-to-0-4-em#16976437 this accepted answer comment.

Comment: Not a great edit, but still nothing that needs flagging.

Comment: Having your questions edited is a perfectly normal thing on Stack Overflow. If you have a fundamental problem with that, maybe the site is not for you.

Answer (score 10):

None of the edits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16829246/revisions) **except yours** were unnecessary or made the formatting worse in any way.

The reason why a list formatted in `1) 2) 3)` requires manual breaking with `<br>` tags is because Markdown lists make use of `1. 2. 3.`, with periods, not closing parentheses. Since using Markdown is the preferred way of formatting, that should have indicated that something wasn't right about your formatting, since you don't find yourself forcing line breaks between `<li>` elements with `<br>` tags in HTML either. In other words, what you used was an *incorrect* way of formatting a list.

I usually leave thanks alone unless it clearly looks as though the asker wrote thanks for the sake of adding unnecessary noise (i.e. the asker doesn't seem genuinely concerned that people are helping in their own time), but there was no harm removing it either. Removing thanks does not make somebody seem rude; however, anybody can come across as rude by saying thanks without meaning it.

And the question tags that were added ([javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[regex](/questions/tagged/regex)) weren't inappropriate for your question. It *does* involve regular expressions in JavaScript after all.

As for determining whether certain formatting is appropriate for a certain post, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Do not flag an edit unless you have a valid reason to believe it was actively harmful.